# set TextView of another activity but not initialized

Tags: android

I have a `FrameLayout` Activity with multiple `TextView` in `TableLayout`. And I want to `click` on a `Button` from another `Activity` `X` may be filled with data and displayed in a `AlertDialog`.

```
I get the following error: "Could not execute method of the activity."
```

see other errors of the same type, but couldn't found the solution.

I can understand that the problem is that I do not have `StartActivity`. But I need not start another `Activity`.

Sorry for my English. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: posting the code would be helpful

Comment: check whether ur button id is correct or not in  findviewbyid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need this? If you are not going to start the Activity and show the textView, why (trying to)set it from outside?

You can use SharedPreferences to save/load the text, and whenever you open the `Activity`, you can set the text by getting from SharedPreferences.

You can set the string on button click:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editor.putString("TAG", "your_string");
editor.commit();
```

You can set the text in your other Activity by loading from SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String text = preferences.getString("TAG", "0");
textView.setText(text);
```